# I need to convert total date to month only

Tags: google-sheets-api

I set up a google forms form for my work where my employees pass information and this information is recorded in a spreadsheet. The information, when recorded, automatically inserts a date and time in the first column of form responses. However, when I enter the code = month (a1), it always returns the answer "1" or "January" and this information does not match the date entered in the column. How do I fix this?

Comment: This is an English language site. Please post in that language, or ask your question at [Stack Overflow em Português}(http://pt.stackoverflow.com) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are entering '=month(a1)' for every row, then you are always taking the month of the top left cell in the sheet.  You would need to adjust the row number for the row you are in.
You could use something like '=month(now())' to ensure you are always getting the month of the current date.